# Price Barrier Options on Baskets using Quantlib

Tags: options, quantlib

Is it possible to price barrier options on a basket of stocks using [Quantlib](http://quantlib.org), e.g. a Worst-of Down-and-in-Put on a basket of 3 stocks?

I already checked the `MCBarrierEngine` (does not support multiple stocks) and the `MCEuropeanBasketEngine` (does not support barrier options), but without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such engine at this time. If you want to code it, you can clone and rename the `MCEuropeanBasketEngine` and the `EuropeanMultiPathPricer` classes.  The new path-pricer class must be modified so that its `operator()` returns the payoff of your option as calculated on a given path; the new engine will be mostly unmodified, except for the `pathPricer` method which of course must now return an instance of the new path-pricer class.

Comment: ok - I see what I can do :)